# Why slots=True makes a dataclass to ignore its default values?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, slots

This code works as expected:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(slots=False, init=False)
class Test:
    field: str = "default value"


print(Test())  # outputs "Test(field='default value')"
```

However, if I change `slots` to `True`, it throws an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'field'
```

To fix the issue, I have to either use the generated `__init__` method or initialize all the fields within a custom `__init__` method explicitly. What is the reasoning behind this behavior?

Answer (score 5):

You're not initializing the object with its default values anyway - your `__init__` isn't initializing the object at all. However, without `__slots__`, it kind of *looks like* the default value is there, because instance attribute lookup falls back to the class, and finds that `field` on the class is set to `"default value"`.

With `slots=True`, `field` on the class isn't set to `"default value"` any more. It's set to a slot descriptor, responsible for retrieving slot values from the right part of the instance's memory layout. Instance attribute lookup finds the slot descriptor, which checks the slot in the instance's memory layout, and finds the slot is empty, so it raises an `AttributeError`.

Comment: And how exactly removing the `__init__` method "fixes" the problem?

Comment: @enkryptor well for starters, because there *shouldn't be one to begin with*. Because *practically* the whole point of `dataclasses.dataclass` to to generate that `__init__`. When you remove it, then the one that `dataclasses.dataclass` generates one for you. And things work.

Comment: @enkryptor I would go as far as to say that *if you are going to write your own `__init__` then just don't use `dataclasses.dataclass`*. You should try to use `__post_init__`, then if that doesn't work, then your use-case is probably outside the scope of what a "dataclass" is supposed to be (which is basically a simple record-type with record-like semantics)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're right, it's in the first paragraph of the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) — "this code will add, among other things, a `__init__()`"